# Retrive from MongoDB by passing client side values to serverside PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, post

How to Pass variable to PHP using a clientside DropDown Menu(in HTML) to perform a search in MongoDB and retrive the relevant key pair accordingly?

**Passing Varibales to serverside PHP**

> mydomain.com/file.php?name=John

For Example if the MongoDB contains the collections as shown below

[{"Name":"John","Age":"54"},{"Name":"Mary","Age":"44"}]

if the Name is passed in the URL via PHP then it should retrieve the corresponding age of the person.

Can anyone point out examples

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php has more example that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link will explain how to get you startet with mongodb and PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php.

And for the client side you would use a HTML form with either the get or post method:

```
<form name="input" action="my_php_file_for_mongodb.php" method="get">
  <select name="username">
   <option value="John">John</option>
   <option value="Sarah Connor">Sarah Connor</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

After submitting this form to the right PHP file (in my example form it's the "my_php_file_for_mongodb.php" file) you can reach the input in PHP by accessing the $_GET variable like so:

```
$name_to_get_from_db = $_GET['username'];
```

After this you would need to follow the examples from my first link to retrieve the data from mongoDB using the input from the $_GET array.

I hope this helps